# Firefox tries to open HTML files when trying to access web pages

Tags: windows-10, firefox, html

Recently I've been getting this weird behavior on Firefox 73.0 (win10) where as I'm trying to open a web page, the page itself won't load but I'll get a prompt to open an HTML file instead. The reload icon will also be greyed out. Closing the tab and trying to load it again works, at least sometimes. There doesn't seem to be a consistent pattern to it nor is it restricted to any specific sites, even opening a new Incognito window sometimes triggers this behavior. It's not very frequent but it happens multiple times a day.

Any idea what this could be and how could I solve it?

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of this weird situation?

Comment: I've (un)fortunately been unable to reproduce this behavior.